# Como levar o valor de um reduce a tag para aparecer na view - VUE.JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuex, quasar

Estou tentando montar um painel, e quero levar os valores somados de um reduce pra aparecer na view

Dentro do orçamentos, há um array de valor, e fiz o methods para somar

```
methods: {
open(os) {
  this.os = os.id;
  this.$axios
    .get(this.apiAtual + 
      "/Orcamento/GetOrcamentos/?" +
        qs.stringify({ os: this.os }, { arrayFormat: "repeat" })
    )
    .then(response => {
      this.readonly = $user.comercial ? false : response.data.readonly;
      if(os.situacao.id >= 3){
        this.readonly = true
      }
      this.orcamentos = response.data.orcamentos;
      this.loading = false;
    });
    },
  }, 

  Computed: {
      valor(){
        const ValorTotal = this.valor
        .reduce((acc, current) => 
          acc + current, 0);
        return ValorTotal;

        console.log(ValorTotal)
      }
    },
  data() {
    return {
      loading: false,
      search: false,
      cliente: null,
      projeto: null,
      situacao: null,
      tipos: null,
      orcamentos: [],
      especialidade: null
```

Gostaria que o valor aparecesse nessa tag

```
    <div class="col-md-2 box box-primy">   
           <span> <p> TOTAL DE ORDEM DE SERVIÇO</p><br></span>
           <span> <h1> {{ValorTotal}}</h1> </span>
    </div>
```

Comment: O nome da propriedade computed chama-se `valor` e não `ValorTotal`, e o `console.log` que tens depois do return é escusado

Comment: então a logica está certa?

Comment: Aparentemente sim, coloca `{{valor}}` em vez de `{{ValorTotal}}`. Não testei mas foi isso que reparei à primeira

Comment: bom, como o valor, pertence a propriedade orcamento, nao deveria ser this orcamento.valor, ou quando vc chama o orcamento em array vc ja tem liberdade pra pegar seus valores internos?

Comment: Como não sei a estrutura da variável `this.valor` não te consigo ajudar, mas o erro à primeira vista que eu vi foi o que disse em cima